# Implement stellar.js parallax with multiple css properties, with start and end points?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I'll be using stellar.js by Mark Dalgeish for some parallax. Previously I was using skrollr but found iPad wasn't functioning as well as I liked it to.

With Skrollr I was able to set start/end points for the animation, including CSS properties for the start/end (and it creates the in between tweenmax style).

With stellar.js it seems I have to create a completely new function for the following properties for one of my animation: display, transform, opacity..

Is there any easy way to do this for all the css properties I'll need now and in future?

Also, I can't seem to find in the docs where I can say, "start this animation when the user has scrolled 300px down the page and stop the animation after they've scrolled 450px down the page". Any ideas on this? The idea was to create an element fading in from the right off screen to about 200px right and then stopping at full opacity.

Feel free to display a fiddle if you're comfortable with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that with [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#shortcuts-examples) if it's an option you would consider. I've linked directly to some examples, see the Scroll Analytics one for instance.

Comment: Thanks pallandt - that's what I was after ;)